# Display Image in mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I have am working in MVC, I want to display  image which is available in in System.Drawing.Image object.

Please give me some solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

```
return new FileContentResult(your.Image, [*ContentType*] )
```

common content types : image/gif , image/jpeg , image/png ...